# In Opera, input are enclosed in black

Tags: html, input, border, opera

Browser: Opera 12

In the browser Opera, if the block contains the one least 2 input, one of which is type = "submit", then pressing the normal input field - input parameters with type = "submit" is allocated a black border.

[image]

Code for the input with the type = "submit":

```
<input type="submit" id="SearchBlock_BtnSearch" value="Search" class="mc-button mc-button-orange"/>
```

Styles:

```
.mc-button {
background: -o-linear-gradient(to bottom, #EEEEEE, #D3D3D3) transparent;
border-bottom: 1px solid #919191;
border-left: 0px solid #919191;
border-radius: 10px;
border-right: 0px solid #919191;
border-top: 0px solid #919191;
clear: none;
color: #676767;
cursor: pointer;
float: left;
font-family: "Myriad Pro", "Arial", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
height: 26px;
letter-spacing: 0.01px;
line-height: 26px;
min-width: 10px;
overflow: visible;
padding: 0px 24px !important;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: 0px 1px #F3F3F3;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

.mc-button-orange { 
background: -o-linear-gradient(to bottom, #EEEEEE, #D3D3D3) transparent;
border-bottom: 1px solid #919191;
color: #676767;
position: relative;
text-shadow: 0px 1px #F3F3F3;
}
```

Tell me, please, how to solve the problem?

Looking ahead, the button has a boarder, for this reason, if we apply the border: none - disappears and a black outline and the border of the button

P.S. Translated by Google Translate

**UPD:**

If at the beginning of CSS to specify the problem disappears:

```
noindex:-o-prefocus, input[type="submit"] {
    border: none;
}

noindex:-o-prefocus, input[type="submit"]:hover {
    border: none;
}
```

However, this solution completely removes the border, which is not desirable

Comment: The border is to indicate that the button is a submit button and will be automatically pressed when user presses ENTER key on any form input except button. To avoid the border, use a normal button and script to mimic the submit button functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
* {
border: 0px;
}
```

at the very start of the css file. This prevent the browser to put his default border

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Does not help.